# How to get a type of enum from the string in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I have an enum:

```
export enum Suit {
  SPADES = "SPADES", 
  HEARTS = "HEARTS", 
  DIAMONDS = "DIAMONDS", 
  CLUBS = "CLUBS"
}
```

And then when I try to use it:

```
for(let suit in Suit) {
    console.log(suit);
    console.log(typeof suit);
    const theSuit: Suit = Suit[suit];
}
```

VS code gives compilation error at `theSuit` says: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Suit'`.

The typescript version is 3.2.2

How should I get a type of `Suit` from the string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a type assertion to tell the compiler `suit` will definitely be a key of `Suit`

```
export enum Suit {
    SPADES = "SPADES", 
    HEARTS = "HEARTS", 
    DIAMONDS = "DIAMONDS", 
    CLUBS = "CLUBS"
}

for(let suit in Suit) {
    console.log(suit);
    console.log(typeof suit);
    const theSuit: Suit = Suit[suit as keyof typeof Suit];
}
```